# MySQL Getting the return of a substraction

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-timestamp

We are trying to get the length of a physical exercise by using the timestamps on our sensor data.

We currently have the following query:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
    SELECT HAAS2.trainingsdata.timestamp
    FROM HAAS2.trainingdata
    WHERE HAAS2.trainingsdata.training_id= 1
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)
- UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
    SELECT HAAS2.trainingsdata.timestamp
    FROM HAAS2.trainingdata
    WHERE HAAS2.trainingsdata.training_id= 1
    ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 1)
AS output
```

(enters added for readability)

When testing this query in phpMyAdmin we get the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>       corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>       near 'SELECT HAAS2.trainingsdata.timestamp FROM HAAS2.trainingdata
>       WHERE HAAS2.trainin' at line 1

We've tried different ways to write down the query all resulting in the same error. We don't understand where the syntax error lies.

Comment: Although you are indeed better off with a different query *(the answer below)*, there is a direct answer to your explicit question; The sub-queries need to be within their own brackets.  `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ( <sub-query> ) ) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ( <sub-query> ) ) AS output`  The brackets you had were only for the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function call, you *also* needed the ones around the sub-query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT max(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)) -
       min(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)) AS output
FROM HAAS2.trainingdata
WHERE training_id = 1
```